# Help with logic

Tags: logic

If I have a theorem, and I show that if I assume that the theorem is not true then I obtain a contradiction, how does this imply that the theorem must be true.

Comment: Can you include an example in your question?

Comment: Initially it would be termed a statement, not a theorem.  It becomes a theorem once you have proved it.  The approach you cite is known as [Reduction Ad Absurdum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum)

Comment: What other possibility is there?

Answer (score 3):

In standard logic, a statement is either true or false (note that this is no longer true in other logic systems). Now a contradiction is, by definition, a false statement, and therefore its negation is true.

Now there's the rule that from $A\implies B$ you get $\lnot B\implies \lnot A$. For example, if "X is a car" implies "X is green", then from "X is not green" you can conclude that "X is not a car" (because otherwise it obviously would have been green).

If $S$ is the statement you want to prove, and $C$ is the contradiction you arrive at, you've just proved that $\lnot S\implies C$, from which it immediately follows that $\lnot C\implies \lnot\lnot S$, that is (again in standard logic) $\lnot C\implies S$. Since for the reason given above, $\lnot C$ is true (it's a tautology, since $C$ is a contradiction), you can then just use normal *modus ponens* (that is the standard rule that if $A$ and $A\implies B$, then $B$) to arrive at $S$.

Note that I've used "in standard logic" here quite a lot. As soon as you deviate from standard logic (e.g. use intuitionistic logic), proofs by contradiction are generally no longer valid.

Comment: I don't understand how you went from $\neg S \implies C$ to $\neg C \implies \neg \neg S$

Comment: @user758575: That's just an application of the rule explained in the paragraph before: Just use $\lnot S$ for $A$ and $C$ for $B$.

Comment: I don't understand your first rule, why is this true could you explain with the analogy more deeply please thanks

Comment: @user758575: Well, look at the example I've given. If from the fact that X is a car you can imply that X is green (that is, if all cars are green), then obviously something which is not green cannot be a car, because otherwise it would have to be both green and not green. Or in general terms: $A\implies B$ means that whenever you find $A$ is true you know that $B$ must also be true. So if you find that $B$ is not true, then you know $A$ cannot be true either because otherwise $B$ should be true, which it isn't.

Comment: Yes I understand that if $X$ were a car and were not green, $X$ would be both green and not green, but how does this imply that if $X$ isn't green then $X$ isn't a car. How does one false statement make this statement true.

Comment: @user758575: What exactly do you refer to in your last sentence?

Comment: If $A\to\bot$ how can I conclude $A$ is not true

Comment: Well, in the rule of the second paragraph, it's a much more limited rule: You don't derive an arbitrary contradiction. You only look at the very specific claim.

Answer (score 0):

Let A denote the theorem you wish to prove. By assuming that it is not true you assume that $\neg A$ is true. Then your assumption of $\neg A$ implies a contradiction, something known to be false. Hence $\neg A\to\bot$ so A must be true.

Comment: Why, how do you know the contradiction isn't a product of some other phenomena

Comment: Because after making the assumption that statement A is false you proceed only through statements previously proven to be correct, logical axioms or nonlogical axioms. All of these are accepted as true so nothing else could cause the contradiction.

Comment: How do I know it caused the contradiction? What if the contradiction was always there?

Comment: @user758575: Then you have an inconsistent system of axioms, in which you can prove anything.